# How to reorder rows in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, order-by

I've got the following table

[image]

And I have to change the order of the rows in an unpredictable way for example:

1. Set the position of the row with `id = 1` after the row with `id = 3` and preserve the ordering of the other rows.
2. Add new row at position 3 right after row with `id = 2`.
3. Delete row from
   position 4

What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: With "reorder" rows, do you mean to update the `"Order"` column of your table to "move" the rows?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, I can insert row in some position and update the other rows but I think if table will grow in size it will affect the performance so I'm searching the better way

Comment: See this answer for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115828/ but there is no way to avoid updating all "following" rows if you want to move one row

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what do you think about using `arrays` for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution, because table rows in PostgreSQL don't have a fixed position in the table. Every `UPDATE` will change the position, and every new row will be inserted wherever there happens to be enough room.

Even if there are no modifications, sequential scans of the table don't necessarily start at the beginning.

The way to order rows is to use an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause with `SELECT`.